# php Как сортировать два ассоцитивных массива по ключу с датой

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

У меня есть два массива с элементами:

### Первый массив

```
    array(
     [0] => array(
     'data'=> '22.06.2015',
     'name'=>'qq',
     'text'=>'privet 4eloveki',
    ),
     [1] => array(
     'data'=> '19.06.2032',
     'name'=>'qaaaq',
     'text'=>'privet aaa',
    ),
```

### Второй массив

```
array(
 [0] => array(
 'data'=> '02.06.2012',
 'name'=>'bbb',
 'text'=>'poka',
),
 [1] => array(
 'data'=> '05.01.1032',
 'name'=>'qaaaq',
 'text'=>'poka aaa',
),
```

### Задача

Получить на выходе один массив и отсортировать элементы по полю 'data' (первыми самые актуальные)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php  можете воспользоватся функцией *usort*

Comment: подскажите, как должна выглядеть колбэк функция в моем случае ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В начале склеиваем массивы, потом применяем сортировку:

```
$mergedArr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);    

usort($mergedArr, function($arr1, $arr2){
    $time1 = strtotime($arr1['data']);
    $time2 = strtotime($arr2['data']);

    if ($time1  == $time2)
        return 0;

    return ($time1 < $time2) ? -1 : 1;
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($mergedArr);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

`array_merge` - Сливает один или большее количество массивов. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php

Но учтите, что если ключи будут не числа, т.е. буду ассоциативные массивы, то merge не получится, т.к

> если входные массивы имеют одинаковые строковые ключи, тогда каждое
>   последующее значение будет заменять предыдущее

`usort` - Сортирует массив по значениям используя пользовательскую функцию для сравнения элементов http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php

---

Кстати в PHP7 `usort` можно написать:

```
usort($mergedArr, function($arr1, $arr2){
    return strtotime($arr1['data']) <=> strtotime($arr2['data']);   
});
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что в этой строке опечатка ?     if (strToTimeFunc($arr1['data']) == strToTimeFunc($arr2['data'])
        return 0; -или какой смысл она несет?

Comment: @tsx я просто экспериментировал и забыл исправить. Теперь там `$time1  == $time2`